# How to get "longest" float number in numpy array (series)?

Tags: pandas, numpy

I Have series of float numbers - [0.1, 0.01, 0.0001, 0.000123]. How can i get "longest" float (not a minimum!) - 0.000123?

Comment: `float(max(map(str, arr), key=len))`

Comment: What do you expect for the output if the input contains, for example, `1e-8` and `1.23456789e-8`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the float numbers to `string` and then use [**`len`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) with [**`pandas.Series.argmax`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.argmax.html) :

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([0.1, 0.01, 0.0001, 0.000123])

float_length = s.astype(str).map(len)
out = s.loc[float_length.argmax()]
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

0.000123
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import numpy as np

# take a list/numpy array of floats and return the longest float
def get_longest(x):
    idx = sorted([(n, len(str(i).split('.')[-1])) for n, i in enumerate(x)], key=lambda x: x[1])[-1][0]
    
    return x[idx]

a = [0.000123, 0.1, 0.01, 0.0001]

print(get_longest(a))
# 0.000123

print(get_longest(np.array(a)))
# 0.000123

b = [0.1, 0.01, 0.0001, 0.000123]

print(get_longest(b))
# 0.000123
```

if you have scientific notation (`float with very long Decimal parts`) in your list/np array:

```
def get_longest(x):
    x = [str(np.format_float_positional(i, trim='-')) for i in x]
    idx = sorted([(n, len(i.split('.')[-1])) for n, i in enumerate(x)], key=lambda x: x[1])[-1][0]
    
    return x[idx]

c = [9e-09, 6.5e-20, 0.1, 0.01] # --> [0.000000009, 0.000000000000000000065, 0.1, 0.01]

print(get_longest(np.array(c)))
# 0.000000000000000000065

print(get_longest(c))
# 0.000000000000000000065
```